# Docusign : How can I ensure that user has to enter name for signing?

Tags: docusignapi

I have the Embedded Signing API. The document shows up fine and the user is allowed to sign and finish. All that is working fine.
Now the business users have a requirement where they want to ensure that the user has to enter their name. Is that possible ?
I tried not sending in the '' attribute in the xml or sending in a blank value for

```
'<name>'
```

But they all come back with an error.
I have to send in a value for

```
'<name>'
```

in the request and that is the name that is shown up automatically in the signature field to be selected. Is it possible to ensure that the user has to enter name in the field and then accept that as a signature ?

Thanks

Update

I am using C# and I have this xml :

```
"<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
            "<status>sent</status>" +
            "<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Embedded Signing example</emailSubject>" +
            "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" +
            "<templateRoles>" +
                "<templateRole>" +
                    "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +
                    "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                    "<roleName>" + templateRole + "</roleName>" +
                    "<clientUserId>" + clientUserId  + "</clientUserId>" + 
                    "<tabs>" +
                        "<textTabs>" +
                            "<anchorString>Full Name</anchorString>" +
                            "<tabLabel>Full Name</tabLabel>" +
                            "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                            "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                            "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                            "<xPosition>24</xPosition>" +
                            "<yPosition>153</yPosition>" +
                            "<value>" + "Enter Name here" +"<value>" +
                            "<required>true</required>" + 
                        "</textTabs>" +
                    "</tabs>" + 
                "</templateRole>" +
            "</templateRoles>" +
            "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

And I get this error:

```
<errorCode>INVALID_REQUEST_BODY</errorCode>
  <message>The request body is missing or improperly formatted. The XML request does not match the expected format. </message>
```

Comment: For embedded signing there are 3 requirements for a signer: name, email@, clientUserID. Since you are already passing in the signers name, you can use the "Full Name" DocuSign tab that will automatically become populated with their name.  If you want to use a blank textbox, then you would want to mark that tab with the 'required' property.

Comment: I do NOT want  "Full Name" DocuSign tab to be automatically populated. I want the user to write or enter their name. How do I go about marking the tab with required property ?

Comment: The documentation has examples - here is one for REST: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Text%20Tab.htm?Highlight=required

Comment: So pass in this Text Tab xml as json when requesting the url ? And "anchorString" should be 'Full Name' ?

Comment: There's several issues I see with the above request.  For starters, you're missing an extra XML node that defines each text Tab.  Next, you need to remove the `anchorString` property since you are using absolute positioning.  You are also missing the closing slash (/) character in your value XML node.  Posting a response that contains all the fixes...

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your business use-case that requires users to type in their name?  Are you trying to create some extra form of acknowledgement or agreement by having them write in their full name into a text field?  If so why not just put a radio button into your envelopes which says something like "I agree to blah blah blah..." and let them choose Yes or No and go from there?  You could even have a conditional field then pop up if they select the Yes button and have them fill in the field then, etc.

With all that said, if still want to set a required, editable data field for signers to type their name into you can do this through the API, you just need to fix the issues I listed in my above comment.  Here's sample XML and JSON that you could use:

```
<textTabs>
    <text>
        <tabLabel>Full Name</tabLabel>
        <locked>true</locked>   
        <required>true</required>   
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
        <recipientId>1</recipientId>
        <xPosition>24</xPosition>
        <yPosition>153</yPosition>
        <value>Enter Name here</value>
    </text> 
</textTabs>
```

And here's the JSON version:

```
"textTabs": [
{
    "tabLabel": "Full Name",
    "locked": "false",
    "required": "true",
    "pageNumber": "1",      
    "documentId": "1",              
    "xPosition": "200",
    "yPosition": "200",
    "value": "Enter Name here"
},
```